# Running CUDA video encoding Sample on linux

Tags: cuda, nvidia, video-encoding, gpu

I downloaded cudaEncode sample from this site for linux or MAC os :

> http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#imaging

but I think it is for windows too and for visual studio, and it's source code like main.cpp and VideoEncoding.cpp is contain header for widows, It does not have Makefile too.

whats wrong ? how can I run it on linux ? Is there another CUDA video encoding sample on GPUs (not NVENC hardware) for Linux (centOS)

Answer (score 1):

I am running into the same problem. I believe that it all comes down to the fact that Windows uses DirectX and Linux and Mac do not. The code in the samples utilize DirectX, which is why it does not run properly on a non-windows OS.